# Discord.py Server Boost Event

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

is there a way to send a message if a new one boosts the server, like a server get boosted event or sth like this?

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def server_get_boosted(self, member):
    print(str(member))
```

sth like this

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way do to this. That's not a limtation of `discord.py`, the Discord API simply doesn't provide such an event.

However, nitro boosters are assigned automatically an irrevocable "nitro booster" role, that you might query as a workaround.

You can do that by checking if the user has a new role -the "nitro booster one"- in the `on_member_update` event.

Source: [this feature request](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360044355652-Nitro-Boost-the-API).

Answer (score 1):

There is no event that is sent specifically on server boost.

However when a server boost message is sent, an `on_message` event is fired. The message will have the `MessageType` of `premium_guild_subscription`.

So you could so something like:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.type == discord.MessageType.premium_guild_subscription:
        print(str(message.author))
```

Sources:

[MessageType](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=messagetype#discord.MessageType)

[premium_guild_subscription](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.MessageType.premium_guild_subscription)